# Linux Tikanga update repository

Tags: php, linux, devops, redhat

I am working on old server with os "Tikanga" not under redhat support

currently I want to build on this server application with Mysql DB and PHP

but I cant install PHP and need some-one to support me

$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.6 (Tikanga)

$ php --version
-bash: php: command not found

Comment: Could you add the command used to install php and the logs ?

Comment: you need to install php, it doesn't come standard on Red Hat (well at least not to my knowledge).